# Making a config change visible to subsequent tasks

Tags: gruntjs

*Using: Grunt 1.01, load-grunt-config, jit-grunt.*

I'm looking to put a simple means of setting a development/production flag in place for use in certain Grunt tasks.

The first task that needs the flag is `webpack.js`, in order to switch between the development and production builds of React. Here's that file:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {

    // Get the task that was invoked from the command line.
    var theTask = process.argv[2];

    // Check to see if it's a production task. If so, change the
    // `env` variable accordingly.
    if ( theTask !== undefined && theTask.indexOf('prod') === 0 ) {
        grunt.config.set('env', 'production');
    }

    return {
        app: {
            entry: './<%= siteInfo.build_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.temp_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.app_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.app_file %>.js',
            output: {
                path: '<%= siteInfo.build_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.temp_dir %>',
                filename: '<%= siteInfo.bundle_file %>.tmp.js'
            },
            stats: false,
            failOnError: true,
            progress: false,
            plugins: [
              new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(grunt.config.data.env)
              }),
            ]
        }
    }

};
```

In the context of this task, it works perfectly. If I run `grunt prod` then the correct version of React is being included in the bundled JS.

However, I was under the (most certainly) mistaken impression that by setting the `env` variable using `grunt.config.set` this update to Grunt's config object would then be available to subsequent tasks.

As I've found out, `env` is `undefined` if I `console.log(grunt.config.data.env)` in another task.

Any pointers or suggestions of alternative approaches appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the config, try this:

Create a pre-build task which sets any config/options prior to running your tasks.  You can check if the task is prod or not by checking `this.name`, and then since it's a simple value, set it using `grunt.option`:

```
function preBuild() {

    grunt.option('env', this.name === 'prod' ? 'production' : 'development');
    grunt.task.run(['task1', 'task2', task3']);
}

grunt.registerTask('prod', preBuild);
grunt.registerTask('dev', preBuild);
```

Using a lo-dash template, you can pass the option value to your config.  Grunt compiles the lo-dash template strings when the task accessing it is run:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    app: {
        entry: './<%= siteInfo.build_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.temp_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.app_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.app_file %>.js',
        output: {
            path: '<%= siteInfo.build_dir %>/<%= siteInfo.temp_dir %>',
            filename: '<%= siteInfo.bundle_file %>.tmp.js'
        },
        stats: false,
        failOnError: true,
        progress: false,
        plugins: [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': "<%= grunt.option('env') %>"
          }),
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Spot on! I tried a similar approach before I posted but from a slightly different angle but it wouldn't work, this one works a treat. Cheers man!

Comment: Only issue I'm having is that `<%= grunt.option('env') %>` isn't working in my task partials, though I'm guessing that's more to do with the fact I'm using load-grunt-config?

Comment: I don't think so?  I'm not using that plugin because I wrote my own function to load modular config files and I have lo-dash templates in mine